# React Native - store Push notifications token in asyncStorage or db?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

I wonder if I should store the token for push notifications in my db (in my user model) or in asyncstorage? It seems that its usually stored in the db but I wonder whats the benefit of that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For example, in my case, I retrieve and the store the token (firestore) in order to send a notification (firebase cloud messaging) to a single or a group of user.

Use case: a customer make an order. And using Firebase Cloud Functions (server side), a notification is sent to the PRO to be informed that a user made an order. You can do this only if you have PRO's token.

Comment: not sure if I understand you but you could always send the token from the client (if stored in asyncstorage) to the backend, the moment someone makes an order

Comment: I guess storing it in the db makes sense if the push notification is not based on user action like a general notification send to all users for example

Comment: There we gooooo

Comment: Why not sending it to the backend as soon as you retrieve it